# Emacs show-paren-mode + Evil

Tags: emacs, emacs24, evil-mode

I'm using Cocoa Emacs24+Evil on OSX. I've enabled the show-paren-mode. However in the normal state, when the cursor is on the closing paren, the paren pair is not highlighted. Only when the cursor is on the opening paren or in the position *after* the closing paren is the paren pair highlighted.

How do I fix this so that in the normal state, the paren pair are highlighted when the cursor is *on* the closing paren and not in the position after it.

Note: This is not happening in Aquamacs based on Emacs23 but is happening in Aquamacs based on Emacs 24.

Answer (score 4):

I had the variable setting

(evil-highlight-closing-paren-at-point-states (quote (not emacs insert replace normal)))

which was causing the problem